# Extra white space on all four sides of ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

This question has been asked many times, but none of the answers helped.

Android adds adds extra white space on all the four sides of image in `ImageView` . And this is same for devices different of different screen size. I have tried changing resolution of the image(s) as well, but to no avail.

For reference, here is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Starter" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="cat"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Also attached is the screenshot how the image looks like.

[image]
[image]

How can I remove these spaces ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove these lines:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

And ensure that the whitespace is not a part of your image file itself.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the padding on your parent layout :)